# Pycharm - Autocomplete not working for External Lib (.so file)

Tags: pycharm

I have a library that has an API via a .so file. Pycharm is unable to index it? Does Pycharm actually have this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, PyCharm indexes binary modules. Search for `sys` module and you'll receive stub built from binaries.

Module should be available from `sys.path` to be indexed by PyCharm.